# How to add drag to a simple pendulum problem function ad hoc?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, oscillators

I recently solved (non-numerically) the differential equation of the simple pendulum problem,

$$y''=-c*\sin(y)\tag{1}.$$

I then tried to solve the equation with drag. I failed. I don't want to solve it numerically because I'm doing this for fun and that would be fun,
$$y''=-c*sin(y)-a*y'\tag{2}.$$

So how would I go about adding drag to $y$ ad hoc, or without actually solving the second differential equation?

The constants of $y$ in my solution shift the equation along the $x$-axis and change the slope at $y(x)=0$ & $|y'(x)|=y'(x)$.

If you give me an equation of how the amplitude should change over time that would also work since the slope and amplitude are directly related.

Comment: Please share your non-numerical solution to the first equation.

Comment: @G.Smith It's a standard result. The solution is an elliptic integral.

Comment: @alephzero Isn’t that for the *period*, not $y(x)$?

Comment: @G. Smith You can use one to find the other.

Comment: Let’s see it then.

Comment: The math is too complicated, but here is f(0)=0, f'(0)=1 up to O(x^13). $x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+2\frac{x^{5}}{5!}-13\frac{x^{7}}{7!}+\frac{161x^{9}}{9!}-\frac{3094x^{11}}{11!}+87773\frac{x^{13}}{13!}$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that you derived a *series* solution.

Comment: Some googling revealed that an exact analytic solution is indeed known.

Comment: Why can you not extend your series solution to handle the drag case?

Comment: Well, actually it's an exact solution. But it can be calculated by series or by a Cauchy integral of the form nobody knows how to solve yet.

Comment: Well. The inverse of the first equation can be turned into a linear differential equation. I tried with the second equation and I failed. It just turned into another nonlinear equation.

Comment: I’m seeing a message to avoid extended discussions, so I won’t dig further.

Answer (score 0):

> I recently solved (non-numerically) the differential equation of the
>   simple pendulum problem.

As @G. wrote in the comments:

> Please share your non-numerical solution to the first equation.

The ODE:

$$y''=-c \sin(y)$$

is usually solved with the *small angle approximation*, which is assumed valid for small angles $y$:

$$\sin(y) \approx y$$

So the ODE becomes:

$$y''=-cy$$

which does have a simple analytical solution:

$$y=C_1\sin(\sqrt{c}x)+C_2\cos(\sqrt{c}x)$$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are integration constants, determined from boundary/initial conditions.

Now if we add the damping term $ay'$, slight reworking gives:

$$y''+ay'+cy=0$$

This is a **second order linear homogeneous ODE** which also has analytical solutions. You can find the algorithm on plenty web resources, just google it.

Comment: Neither I nor, I assume, the OP are interested in the well-known small-angle approximation. But this answer is useful to others who are.